# How to make caption with fixed width on full width responsive jssor slider

Tags: jssor

I'm trying to make full width resposive slider with captions here: http://lesan.com.ua/sborkamebeli/

The problem is that captions is also scaleable and resizes with the slider. What I need is a captions with fixed width and height on responsive slider. Is that possible?

Searched on the stackoverflow and in documentation and couldn't find the answer. Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Everything in Jssor Slider should be scaled along with the slider.

What you can do is to create your own animation and place it above the slider.